# Does 32-Bit OS need hardware virtualization to run o KVM?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, whonix

I have a 64-bit CPU that doesn't support virtualization. My understanding is Whonix is a 32 bit OS. Will I be able to run Whonix on KVM?

Answer (score 1):

64-bit CPUs are usually capable of nativley running 32-bit code.  It is possible to run a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit processor.  You can test with a bootable 32-bit DVD or USB.

If you had a 32-bit CPU you would not be able to run a 64-bit virtual machine natively.  An emulator could run the code, but very slowly.

Comment: Well, I tried using KVM but it didn't work. I had to use VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Also you need to have a qemu-kvm and libvirt-bin packages installed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We expect answers to be more comprehensive here. Please [edit] your answer and add some details. For example, what distribution's packages are these? How would you install them? What do they do?